# Run a forged request through Spring Boot

Tags: java, servlets, spring-boot

What I am trying to do is essentially "simulate" a request when run through Spring Boot. Towards that effect, I have two classes:

```
class HttpServletResponsePassthrough extends HttpServletResponseWrapper
class HttpServletRequestPassthrough extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
```

What both these classes do is essentially store the response data/cookies/headers etc. set during execution and can be retrieved later. The convinience function in `HttpServletResponsePassthrough` is:

```
String HttpServletResponsePassthrough.getRequestBody()
```

This is done by overridng `HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()` and `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()`, which are both backed by a `ByteArrayBuffer`.

Now, to simulate a request, say on `/hello/world`, what I do is:

```
@Autowired WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

public String simulateRequest() {
    // make(..) correctly sets any headers/the correct path and the POST/GET method
    HttpServletRequestPassthrough passthroughRequest = make("/hello/world", ...);
    HttpServletResponsePassthrough passthroughResponse = make(...);

    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = 
        this.webApplicationContext
            .getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher("/hello/world");

    requestDispatcher.forward(passthroughRequest, passthroughResponse);
    return passthroughResponse.getRequestBody();
}
```

Now, the above method works perfectly well for `GET` requests:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/world", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, String> helloWorldGet() {
        reutrn new HashMap<>(...);
    }
}
```

However, if I change it to POST:

```
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/world", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, String> helloWorldPost(@RequestBody Map<String, String> inputJson) {
        System.out.println("I AM IN POST");
        reutrn new HashMap<>(...);
    }
}
```

The `requestBody` is untouched. `getOutputStream` or `getWriter` never gets called on the passthrough object. Even `I AM IN POST` does not get printed.

I apologize for this long wall of text, but I wanted to give as much detail as possible. I am really not sure what goes on inside Spring Boot, specifically how they have implemented their Servlets because of which I am not sure if this is the right way of getting the RequestDispatcher or not. What really surprises me is that it works for GET and not POST.

Comment: You might be interested in Spring's [MVC Test Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-framework)

Answer (score 0):

So, whatever is mentioned above works. The only reason it was not working with my POST requests is because I had a `@RequestBody` annotation on the method, and it expects a `Content-type: application/json` media-type (specifically, the `HttpMessageCovnertor` which can deal with serializing to/from JSON objects to/from Java objects returns it as a part of its `supportedMediaTypes()`).. and I was not setting the header in the request.